# Is there a way to start a server-like notebook?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, python-server-pages

Apologies if this is not strictly a programming question, if someone has a better avenue for asking this question, please do let me know. I have been searching for answers, but not finding quite what I am looking for.

There is Jupyter notebook, which is quite great. I would like to have something like a public Jupyter notebook that runs on a server and allows users to connect to run a *specific* Python script that accepts input from standard input. It is essentially a replacement for them to ssh to a server and run the program on their own.

I get the sense it should be possible to do with Jupyter notebook, but not quite sure how. Is it indeed possible? If not, what the alternatives are?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe these?:

Jupyter hub:

- https://jupyter.org/hub
- https://github.com/jupyterhub/jupyterhub

Colaboratory by Google:

- https://colab.research.google.com/